# Bitwise Representation for Days in month

Tags: .net, enums, bitwise-operators

I would like to be able to a flag enum for the days of the month.

Current I have found many examples for the month of year or day of week and they are based on a enum : short and use the hex format to specify the value of the items.

However I believe a short is to small for 31 days + a last day option. I think an int would do but I am stuck at working out how to implement this and allow for bitwise operations to occur.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Yes but I believe the to perform bitwise operation each bit needs to be isolated from the other bits. So bit 1 may represent the first day and bit 2 the second. Therefore to see if both first day and second day being selected the binary would have to be 00000011. Therefore the max independant days is less than the actual max number of the data structure.

Comment: you are of course correct!

Comment: why are you concerned with saving a few bytes?

Comment: I am really just wondering if the is an example of an enum decorated with the flag option that could hold items more that short. If there is I would love to see it to see how it is done.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have worked it out here is the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Values for days of the month (1, 2, etc., Last Day)  These carry the Flags
/// attribute so DaysOfTheMonth and be combined with | (or).
/// </summary>
[Flags]
public enum DaysOfTheMonth : uint
{
    Day01 = 0x1,
    Day02 = 0x2,
    Day03 = 0x4,
    Day04 = 0x8,
    Day05 = 0x10,
    Day06 = 0x20,
    Day07 = 0x40,
    Day08 = 0x80,
    Day09 = 0x100,
    Day10 = 0x200,
    Day11 = 0x400,
    Day12 = 0x800,
    Day13 = 0x1000,
    Day14 = 0x2000,
    Day15 = 0x4000,
    Day16 = 0x8000,
    Day17 = 0x10000,
    Day18 = 0x20000,
    Day19 = 0x40000,
    Day20 = 0x80000,
    Day21 = 0x100000,
    Day22 = 0x200000,
    Day23 = 0x400000,
    Day24 = 0x800000,
    Day25 = 0x1000000,
    Day26 = 0x2000000,
    Day27 = 0x4000000,
    Day28 = 0x8000000,
    Day29 = 0x10000000,
    Day30 = 0x20000000,
    Day31 = 0x40000000,
    DayLast = 0x80000000
}
```

Comment: You can make it much more readable by using `1 << x` instead it would just be 1 - the number of the day, so `Day01 = 1 << 0, Day02 = 1 << 1, Day03 = 1 << 2 ... Day29 = 1 << 28, Day30 = 1 << 29, Day31 = 1 << 30`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an enum, you can use a 4-byte integer to store the value and compare against a day number expressed as integer which may be more convenient.

In the code below (using C#) the days 31 (left-most bit), 3 and 1 are marked as selected. I'm not using the lowest bit which you can use for a special flag. You can check the code below to see how to read if a day is selected:

```
Int32 selected = Convert.ToInt32("10000000000000000000000000001010", 2);

for (int day = 1; day <= 31; day++)
{
    int dayMask = 1 << day;
    bool isSelected = (selected & dayMask) != 0;
}
```

To select days, you can use the code below:

```
Int32 toSelect = 0;

// select day 1
toSelect = toSelect | (1 << 1);

// select day 3
toSelect = toSelect | (1 << 3);

// select day 31
toSelect = toSelect | (1 << 31);
```